# I'm suddently not able to run server manage.py django since I upgrade my PyCharm

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I can run server to test my webapp. Since I upgrade my PyCharm I cant run it.
I dont know how to do
Bellow is the error output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\migue\PycharmProjects\research4medjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\migue\PycharmProjects\research4medjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\migue\PycharmProjects\research4medjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\migue\PycharmProjects\research4medjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\migue\PycharmProjects\research4medjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\migue\PycharmProjects\research4medjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\migue\PycharmProjects\research4medjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\migue\PycharmProjects\research4medjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 598, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\migue\PycharmProjects\research4medjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 583, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\migue\PycharmProjects\research4medjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 301, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Users\migue\PycharmProjects\research4medjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 307, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Users\migue\PycharmProjects\research4medjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 347, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Users\migue\PycharmProjects\research4medjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 363, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\Users\migue\PycharmProjects\research4medjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 262, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\Users\migue\PycharmProjects\research4medjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 103, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\Users\migue\PycharmProjects\research4medjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 139, in iter_modules_and_files
    if not path.exists():
  File "C:\Users\migue\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 1291, in exists
    self.stat()
  File "C:\Users\migue\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 1111, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)
  File "C:\Users\migue\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 371, in wrapped
    return strfunc(str(pathobj), *args)
OSError: [WinError 123] (File name, directory name or volume label syntax incorrect) when using __file__ '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

Comment: If you activate your virtual environment and do `python manage.py runserver` in the terminal or a cmd prompt, does it work then? If not Id assume your environment is the issue and not PyCharm.

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: You are right Sir, The venv is the problem. When I deactivate my virtual enviroment, it works normally. But I have no clue what I can do to solve the problem

Comment: Try deleting the environment and using PyCharm to create a new one. Then reload the IDE and all of your run scripts and terminals will be using that environment.